# Error: This component already exists in PackageX which PackageA depends on. You can't include the same component in both packages

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

> Error: You're trying to include RecordType > NAMESPACE__CustomObject__c.NAMESPACE__Recordtype_Name in Package
> MyPackageName 1.X.X.  This component already exists in Package null,
> which Package MyPackageName 1.X.X depends on. You can't include the
> same component in both packages

We have a Gen1 managed packaged that we have extend an integration with deploying unmanaged code.
In that unmanaged code deployment, we are able to add Custom Object RecordType picklist values and workflows to custom objects to that installed managed package.

We are attempting to convert the unmanaged code into a Gen2 Unlocked package, with the dependency listed in the project.json.

However, when I try to create the Unlocked package it fails with the above error.

It doesn't seem right you can deploy the code to the org with the installed package no problem, but creating an Unlocked package does not work.

Is the dependency in the package.json the issue?

Do we need to add the new RecordType picklist values in a post install script?  What about the amended workflow?

Comment: So, this may require specific knowledge that we don't necessarily have much of here on SFSE. However, do not fear, I've asked for help in the [DX Group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000C3FpiSAF). I would expect someone to get back to us by tomorrow.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to explain exactly when you get the error, what the sfdx-project.json looks like for the new unlocked package and what is installed where when the error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... add Custom Object RecordType picklist values and workflows to custom objects to that installed managed package

Picklist values are not independently packageable, nor are alterations to the enabled picklist values for existing Record Types. If you include the top-level components that include these changes (a `CustomObject` entity) in your unlocked 2GP, you'll get an error, because that `CustomObject` is already owned by your 1GP.

There's a separate issue with Workflow Rules, and I don't think there's currently a Known Issue for this. As far as I know, packaging a Workflow Rule in a 2GP on a Custom Object that is owned by a different package will fail because it's treated as if it were in fact re-packaging that Custom Object.

If you're actually just trying to change an existing Workflow (you mention an "amended" Workflow), the same principle applies as with picklist values: you cannot package an internal change to a top-level metadata entity owned by another package.

So in the end, what you're trying to do cannot be done with packaging. You can either include these changes in your 1GP, or deliver them unmanaged, but you cannot deliver them in a 2GP extension package.

Comment: Yes, i think it's useful to consider that packaging and deployment source/metadata are two different beasts "independently packageable" is the key point here, I often find it useful to think "could I even do this in 1GP....?" if not, chances are you can't in 2GP either

Comment: Thank you David!